# Flutter Embeded POS Printer

Tags: flutter, embedded, thermal-printer

I am seeking for your help to print from the Z92 POS Embedded printer.
I am googling, but no solution.

[image]

Comment: https://twitter.com/pietervander/status/1564498943232319488?s=20&t=5p9j0gcLXR5_6p9u3ZxJKQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So... You will going to need the Z92 SDK.
Try this SDK:
https://www.xmatp.com/category/downloads/33

You know how work with flutter channels?
Because you will code this SDK in the native Android layer.

check the doc:
https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/platform-channels?tab=android-channel-java-tab

Comment: The xmatp link you posted is dead